# AntiSamy for TinyMce style attributes

Tags: java, tinymce, xss, antisamy

I'm using the antisamy on text i get from tinymce editor.

I'm using the "antisamy-tinymce-1.4.4.xml" file from [owaspantisam](http://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/downloads/list). (as the policy file).

My problem is that it destroys all of the style tags attributes of the string i get from the tinymce editor. 
for example: If i have a text which part of it is in red color , and other part is underlined - the string i will get after cleaning the html with antisamy will be all in the same color and it saves only the underline style attribute. how can i save other style attributes?? Is it worng to change the xml so it wont ignore style attributes?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always change the policy file according to your needs. check for property

```
<property name="color" description="">
```

under css-rules. check whether the color given matches the validation rules specified there.